# go get command of golang is not responding

Tags: go

I am facing a strange situation. I tried to run:

```
go get -x github.com/hooklift/gowsdl
cd.
git clone https://gopkg.in/inconshreveable/log15.v2 /home/usr_a/gocode/src/gopkg.in/inconshreveable/log15.v2
```

And I don't see this command giving any response. It never returns.

This is my `$GOPATH`:

```
/home/usr_a/gocode
```

and `$GOROOT`:

```
/usr/local/go/
```

However, the version shows like this:

```
go version go1.4.2 linux/amd64
```

Any idea, where am I going wrong or can point me to the way we install github module in golang?

Comment: Call `go get` with `-x` command line flag to see what go get is doing. And do not set GOROOT.

Comment: What version of git do you have?

Comment: git version 1.7.1 @JimB

Comment: update git. That's old and doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because of old version of git.